# How can I fix this error for popping a word in a list/string? (Python 3.x)

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, python-3.8

I'm not exactly the kind of guy you call "good" at coding. In this particular scenario, on line 13, I'm trying to pop the first word in the list until I'm done, but it keeps giving me the 'str' object can not be interpreted as an integer issue.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
n = n.split(" ")
N = n[0]
K = n[1]
f1 = input()
f1 = f1.split(" ")
f1 = list(f1)
current = 0
for x in f1:
    while current <= 7:
        print(x)
        f1 = list(f1.pop()[0])
        current = current + len(x)
        if current > 7:
            print("\n")
            current = 0
```

Comment: With your variable naming, it's hard to tell what your code is supposed to do in the end. Can you explain what you're going for?

Comment: Could you share some sample inputs and expected outputs, then explain the error would be easier... Also good tips - choose some `meaningful` variable names.

Comment: @AKX I am practicing a USACO problem. Here's the link: http://www.usaco.org/index.php?page=viewproblem2&cpid=987

Comment: @DanielHao sorry for my choice in variable names... I didn't know what to name them, maybe check my other comment?

Comment: You may want to consider e. g. "input_words", "current_line_length", "word" as suitable variable names...

Comment: @AKX What I'm trying to do is for every K characters, it goes to a new line and writes the words, for example if I put in 10 and 7 in the input, and "Thanks for helping", then I would get an output of "Thanks \n for \n helping"

Comment: For one, you probably don't mean to be modifying f1 with pop while iterating over it (the for loop)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According your comments, this program will split lines to contain max `K` characters:

```py
K = 7
s = "hello my name is Bessie and this is my essay"

out, cnt = [], 0
for word in s.split():
    l = len(word)
    if cnt + l <= K:
        cnt += l
        if not out:
            out.append([word])
        else:
            out[-1].append(word)
    else:
        cnt = l
        out.append([word])

print("\n".join(" ".join(line) for line in out))
```

Prints:

```
hello my
name is
Bessie
and this
is my
essay
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try splitting the string on the index, and inserting a newline there.  Each time you do this your string gets one character longer, so we can use enumerate (which starts counting at zero) to add a number to our slice indexes.

```
s = 'Thanks for helping me'

new_line_index = [7,11, 19]

for i, x in enumerate(new_line_index):
    s = s[:x+i] + '\n' + s[x+i:]
    
print(s)
```

Output

```
Thanks 
for 
helping 
me
```